# Calling external command in find and using pipe

Tags: bash, unix, aix

I am wondering if there is a way to search for all the files from a certain directory including subdirectories using a find command on AIX 6.x, before calling an external command (e.g. hlcat) to display/convert them into a readable format, which can then be piped through a grep command to find a pattern instead of using loops in the shell?

```
e.g. find . -type f -name “*.hl7” -exec hlcat {} | grep -l “pattern” \;
```

The above command would not work and I have to use a while loop to display the content and search for the pattern as follows:

```
find . -type f -name “*.hl7” -print | while read file; do
hlcat $file | grep -l “pattern”;
done
```

At the same time, these HL7 files have been renamed with round brackets which prevent them from being open without having to include double quotes around the file name.

```
e.g. hlcat (patient) filename.hl7 will fail to open.
        hlcat “(patient) filename.hl7” will work.
```

In short, I am looking for a clean concise one-liner approach within the find command and view and search their content these HL7 files with round bracket names.

Many thanks,
George

P.S. HL7 raw data is made up of one continuous line and is not readable unless it is converted into a workable reading format using tools such as hlcat.
in

Comment: Have you tried ? `find . -type f -name “*.hl7” -exec hlcat {} \; | grep -l “pattern”`

Comment: `find . -exec a-script-that-encapsulates-the-complex-command {} \;`.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Comment: I am looking for the files with the pattern in them. There are files in the current directory with these patients.

bash-4.3$ find . -type f -name "*patient*.*" -exec hlcat {} \; | egrep -l "Barry|Jolene"
(standard input)
(standard input)
………

bash-4.3$ cat search_patient.sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
hlcat $1 | awk -F"|" '{ if ($1 == "^PID" && ($5 ~ /Barry|Jolene/)) { print FILENAME }}'

bash-4.3$ find . -type f -name "* patient*.*"  -exec ./search_patient.sh {} \;  # Didn’t find the file with this patient.
bash-4.3$

It didn't find the files with the patients in them.

Comment: How does search_patient.sh pickup each file found by the find command? Does find pass each file as a parameter (e.g. $1) to search_patient.sh one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update: The easy way

```
find . -type f -name '*.hl7' -exec grep -iEl 'Barry|Jolene' {} +
```

**note:** You may get some false positives though. See below for a targeted search.

---

### Searching for a *first name* in a bunch of HL7*v2* files:

###### 1. Looking into the HL7**v2** file format

Example of HL7*v2* `PID` segment:

```
PID|||56782445^^^UAReg^PI||KLEINSAMPLE^BARRY^Q^JR||19620910|M|||
```

`PID` Segment decomposition:

| Seq | NAME | HHIC USE | LEN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PID keyword | Segment Type | 3 |
| 3 | Patient ID | Medical Record Num | 250 |
| 5 | Patient Name | Last^First^Middle | 250 |
| 7 | Date/Time Of Birth | YYYYMMDD | 26 |
| 8 | Sex | F, M, or U | 1 |

###### 2. Writing targeted searches

With `grep` (AIX):

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.hl7' -exec grep -iEl '^PID\|([^|]*\|){4}[^^|]*\^(Barry|Jolene)\^' {} +
```

With `awk`:

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.hl7' -exec awk -v firstname='^(Barry|Jolene)$' '
    BEGIN { FS="|" }
    FNR == 1 { if( found ) print filename; found = 0; filename = FILENAME }
    $1 == "PID" { split($6, name, "^"); if (toupper(name[2]) ~ toupper(firstname)) { found = 1 } }
    END { if ( found ) print filename }
' {} +
```

**remark:** The good part about this `awk` solution is that you pass the *first name regexp* as an **argument**. This solution is easily extendable, for example for searching the *last name*.

Comment: bash-4.3$ find . -type f -name "* patient *.*" -exec sh -c 'for file; do hlcat "$file" | egrep -l " Barry|Jolene"; done' {} +
(standard input)
(standard input)
………..

bash-4.3$ find . -type f -name "*patient*.*" -exec sh -c 'for file; do hlcat "$file" | egrep -q -l "Barry|Jolene" && printf "%s\n" "$file"; done' {} +
file1.hl7
file2.hl7
………….

bash-4.3$ find . -type f -name "*patient*.*" -exec hlcat {} + | egrep -q -l "Barry|Jolene"
bash-4.3$

Comment: -q keeps the (standard input) but does nothing for the search.
-print0 does exist in AIX and doesn’t print newline for each file listed. I am fine with using -print (with newline).

Comment: None of the above suggestions has worked so far. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @GeorgeJackson Added examples to my answer. Also corrected an error with the `find` embedded `-exec sh -c` script which needs a dummy argument before `{} +`

Comment: The following suggestion worked for me:
find . -type f -name '*.hl7' -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        cat "$f" | egrep -q "Barry|Jolene" && printf "%s\n" "$f"; 
    done
' _ {} +
Many thanks for your effort.